# Zoho email forwarding

Tags: email, gmail, forwarding, zoho

Currently I've setup 4 accounts at *zoho mail: a@site,  b@site, c@site, all@site*.
a,b and c are forwarding their mails to *gmail* accounts whereas *all@site* is forwarding mail to a,b and c.

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

1. all@site receives an e-mail ->  it forwards it to a@site, b@site,
   c@site
2. a@site receives an e-mail from all@site -> forwards it to the gmail
   forwarded account
3. c@site receives an e-mail from all@site -> forwards it to the gmail
   forwarded account
4. b@site receives an e-mail from all@site -> forwards it to the gmail
   forwarded account

The problem is that when I send an email to *all@site*, it just forwards it to a,b,c@site, but those 3 accounts do not forward those emails to the respective *gmail* accounts.

I would like to know if there is any easy way to achieve this as this is very important.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zoho doesn't allow multi-forwarding as it may create a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Late maybe, but i just figured a workaround for a similar situation: keep a@..,b@.. and c@.. to forward to their gmail account and instead of adding just your domain emails to the all@.., also add the gmail accounts. just tested it and it works just fine.